# Sonata Admin Bundle ACL don't grant edit

Tags: symfony, acl, sonata-admin, sonata, sonata-user-bundle

I integrated the Sonata Admin Bundle with ACL, and have the following configs:

## config.yml

```
sonata_admin:
    security:
       handler: sonata.admin.security.handler.acl

       # acl security information
       information:
           GUEST:    [VIEW, LIST]
           MAINTAINER:    [EDIT, LIST]
           STAFF:    [EDIT, LIST, CREATE]
           EDITOR:   [OPERATOR, EXPORT]
           ADMIN:    [MASTER]

      # permissions not related to an object instance and also to be available when objects do not exist
      # the DELETE admin permission means the user is allowed to batch delete objects
      admin_permissions: [CREATE, LIST, DELETE, UNDELETE, EXPORT, OPERATOR, MASTER]

      # permission related to the objects
      object_permissions: [VIEW, EDIT, DELETE, UNDELETE, OPERATOR, MASTER, OWNER]
```

## security.yml

security:

```
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_OPERATOR:
        - ROLE_ADMIN_BOOKING_ADMIN
        - ROLE_ADMIN_PAYMENT_ADMIN
```

The flow is we create a booking object via `BookingAdmin` class and in postPersist doctrine event listener I create the payment Object.

```
$payment = new Payment();
//... set here
$this->entityManager->persist($payment);
$this->entityManager->flush();
```

The problem is in list I'm not able to see the edit button, but I can delete.

And when run manual the command:

```
php bin/console sonata:admin:generate-object-acl
```

after that I'm able to see the edit button.

What I do wrong here ? Because I'm logged with the same user.

## EDIT

After few research I found the next problem https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/2-3/doc/reference/security.html#acl-and-friendsofsymfony-userbundle

`A listener must be implemented that creates the object Access Control List with the required rules if objects are created outside the Admin`

What this mean, and how I should do in listener to take the correct ACL role?

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't pointed out your allowed action detailed enough ... you only point to the admin with e.g. "ROLE_ADMIN_BOOKING_ADMIN" ... following the documentation, the config should be "ROLE_ADMIN_BOOKING_ADMIN_EDIT" for example to allow this role to edit your admin ... write "ROLE_ADMIN_BOOKING_ADMIN_ALL" to allow to edit everything ...

Comment: The only roles that I have in `acl_security_identities` is `ROLE_ADMIN_PAYMENT_ADMIN`, `ROLE_ADMIN_PAYMENT_EDITOR`, `ROLE_ADMIN_PAYMENT_GUEST`, `ROLE_ADMIN_PAYMENT_MAINTAINER` and `ROLE_ADMIN_PAYMENT_STAFF`

Comment: Yes, but it seems theres are no permissions pointed out. Did you tried to give your roles the permissions? Like "ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_DEMO_FOO_VIEW" or "ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_DEMO_FOO_ALL"

Comment: Like I said in EDIT, the problem was the object not apply the security rules, and I found If I used this in event listener will add the correct rules to object `$this->serviceContainer->get('admin.booking')->createObjectSecurity($booking);` I don't how correctly is this implementation but for me worked.